# Put, in matrix form: $t_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{w_j-w_i}{1+e^{-(x_i-x_j)}}$, $\forall i=1,2,...,n$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I have the set of equalities
$$t_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{w_j-w_i}{1+e^{-(x_i-x_j)}}, \ \ \forall i=1,2,...,n$$
and I try to write them in a more concise form. I tried to do so:
$$t_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{w_j}{1+e^{-(x_i-x_j)}}-w_i\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{1+e^{-(x_i-x_j)}}, \ \ \forall i=1,2,...,n$$
that is:
$$t_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} w_j-w_i\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}, \ \ \forall i=1,2,...,n$$
$$\Rightarrow \ d_i=[A\ w]_i-[D\ w]_i, \ \ \forall i=1,2,...,n$$
where $A$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-(x_i-x_j)}}$, $D$ the $n\times n$ matrix whose i-th diagonal entry is $d_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}$. Therefore, we have the following matrix relationship
$$t=(A-D)w$$
Could you tell me if my procedure is correct, please? Or you would have done otherwise?

Thanks in advance.